# Sorting ArrayList to descend last name or number

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have ArrayList to hold Employee's records. Employee class was extended from Person class. I need to sort the arrayList in descending order on the last name and then salary in each data. I already used the comparator and collection to do the sort stuff but it did not work. It is because there is no sorted data in output section. See my output on below. Can you help me to find why it does not work? Thanks!

Output:

```
//Show employee's record

Full Name: Tom Jones
Social Security Number: 123-00-129
Date of Birth: 02-02-1992
Email Address: tj@xyz.com
Phone Number: 408-889-999

Employee ID: 1234A
Employee's salary: 50250.0
When an employee is hired: 01-12-2014
Department Section: Math
Regular hourly rate for a week: 0.0


Full Name: Sarah Carly
Social Security Number: 123-98-0012
Date of Birth: 12-12-1995
Email Address: scarly@gmail.com
Phone Number: 215-551-0001

Employee ID: 9876B
Employee's salary: 0.0
When an employee is hired: 09-06-1989
Department Section: History
Regular hourly rate for a week: 0.0


Full Name: Billy Goodwin
Social Security Number: 001-02-003
Date of Birth: 07-12-1965
Email Address: bgreat@kl.org
Phone Number: 555-555-1133

Employee ID: 0012C
Employee's salary: 100200.0
When an employee is hired: 10-02-1967
Department Section: Administration
Regular hourly rate for a week: 0.0

//This one is supposed to show the sorted data but it is blank.

Sort Order
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

*
```

This is main body:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();


    Person p2 = new Employee("Tom", "Jones", "02-02-1992", "tj@xyz.com", "408-889-999", "123-00-129", "1234A", 50250, "01-12-2014", 10.2, 42.0, "Math");
    people.add(p2);

    Person p3 = new Employee("Sarah", "Carly", "12-12-1995", "scarly@gmail.com", "215-551-0001", "123-98-0012", "9876B", 0.0, "09-06-1989", 6.7, 56, "History");
    people.add(p3);

    Person p4 = new Employee("Billy", "Goodwin", "07-12-1965", "bgreat@kl.org", "555-555-1133", "001-02-003", "0012C", 100200, "10-02-1967", 0.0, 0, "Administration");
    people.add(p4);

    for(Person list:people) {System.out.println(list);}



    System.out.println("Sort Order");
    Collections.sort(people, byLastName());    


}

private static Comparator<Person> byLastName()
 {
return new Comparator<Person>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return p2.getLastName().compareTo(p3.getLastName());
    }
};
```

}

This is Person class:

```
public class Person {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String emailAddress;

    String birthDate;
    String phoneNum;
    String socialSecurityNum;


    public Person() {

    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    birthDate = "";

    emailAddress = "";
    phoneNum = "";
    socialSecurityNum = "";


    }

     public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String emailAddress, String phoneNum, String socialSecurityNum) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;

    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    this.socialSecurityNum = socialSecurityNum;

    }


    public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
}

    public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
}

public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

    public String getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() {
            return phoneNum;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNum() {
            return socialSecurityNum;
    }

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum) {
            this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNum(String socialSecurityNum) {
            this.socialSecurityNum = socialSecurityNum;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String display;

        display = ("\n" +"Full Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\nSocial Security Number: "
                    + socialSecurityNum + "\nDate of Birth: " + birthDate
                    + "\nEmail Address: " + emailAddress + "\nPhone Number: " + phoneNum 
                    + "\n");

            return display;
}

int compareTo(Person get) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}




 }
```

This is Employee class:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    private String empID;
    private double salary;
    private String dateHired;

    private double rate;            
    private double hours;
    private String department;

    public Employee() {

    empID = "";
    salary = 0.0;
    dateHired = "";

    rate = 0.0;
    hours = 0.0;
    department = "";


    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String emailAddress, String phoneNum, String socialSecurityNum) {

super(firstName, lastName, birthDate, emailAddress, phoneNum, socialSecurityNum);
    };

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String emailAddress, String phoneNum, String socialSecurityNum, 
    String empID, double salary, String dateHired, double rate, double hour, String department) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;

    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    this.socialSecurityNum = socialSecurityNum;


    this.empID = empID;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.dateHired = dateHired;

    this.rate = rate;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.department = department;

}


    public String getEmpID() {
            return empID;
}

    public double getSalary() {
            return salary;
}

public String getDateHired() {
    return dateHired;
}

    public double getRate() {
            return rate;
    }

    public double getHours() {
            return hours;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
            return department;
    }

public void setEmpID(String empID) {
    this.empID = empID;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public void setDateHired(String dateHired) {
    this.dateHired = dateHired;
}

    public void setRate(double rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
    }

    public void setHours(double hours) {
            this.hours = hours;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
            this.department = department;
    }

    public double calculateHourlyRate(double rate, double hours) {
        return this.rate * this.hours;
    }

    public String EmployeeInfo() {

        return "Employee ID: " + empID + "\nDepartment Section: " + department
                + "\nPay Rate: " + rate + "\nWork Hours: " + hours;
                        }

    public String PersonInfo() {

        String info;

        info = ("\n" +"Full Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\nSocial Security Number: "
                    + socialSecurityNum + "\nDate of Birth: " + birthDate
                    + "\nEmail Address: " + emailAddress + "\nPhone Number: " + phoneNum 
                    + "\n");

            return info; }

    public boolean equals(Employee otherEmployee) {

            return (empID == otherEmployee.empID
            && salary == otherEmployee.salary
            && dateHired == otherEmployee.dateHired
           && rate == otherEmployee.rate
          && hours == otherEmployee.hours
         && department == otherEmployee.department);
    }

    public Employee getCopy() {

            Employee temp = new Employee();

            temp.empID = empID;
            temp.salary = salary;
            temp.dateHired = dateHired;

            temp.rate = rate;
            temp.hours = hours;
            temp.department = department;

            return temp;
    }   

    public void makeCopy(Employee otherEmployee) {

            empID = otherEmployee.empID;
            salary = otherEmployee.salary;
            dateHired = otherEmployee.dateHired;

            rate = otherEmployee.rate;
            hours = otherEmployee.hours;
            department = otherEmployee.department;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String display;

        display = ("\n" +"Full Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\nSocial Security Number: "
                    + socialSecurityNum + "\nDate of Birth: " + birthDate
                    + "\nEmail Address: " + emailAddress + "\nPhone Number: " + phoneNum 
                    + "\n" + "\n" +"Employee ID: " + empID + "\nEmployee's salary: "
                    + salary + "\nWhen an employee is hired: " + dateHired
                    + "\nDepartment Section: " + department + "\nRegular hourly rate for a week: " 
                    + calculateHourlyRate(rate, hours) + "\n");

            return display;
}

    public void PrintEmployeeInfo() {

        System.out.print(EmployeeInfo());
    }

    public void PrintPersonInfo() {

        System.out.print(PersonInfo());
    }

    public void PrintCalculateHourlyRate() {

        System.out.print(calculateHourlyRate(rate, hours));
    }
```

Comment: `it did not work` ? what does that mean ?

Comment: When I run the program, there is no sorted data in output section. it should be there so i assume it does not work.

Comment: @user3429089 You're printing the list before you sort it.

Comment: Yeah, I want to show the list before sorting it. I don't know how to print the sorted list.

Comment: @user3429089 You're only printing the unsorted list. If you want to output the sorted list you need to do `for(Person list:people) {System.out.println(list);}` again after the `Collections.sort(people, byLastName());` line. `Collections.sort` only sorts it and won't print it.

Comment: Oh, I get it! I should do it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comparator you're always comparing p2 and p3, it should probably be this:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.getLastName().compareTo(y.getLastName());
    }
```

Also, if you want to compare on multiple properties you need to change the evaluation to include the other property as well.

The reason you're not getting any sorted output is that you're only printing the unsorted list. If you want to output the sorted list you need to do `for(Person list:people) {System.out.println(list);}` again after the `Collections.sort(people, byLastName());` line. `Collections.sort` only sorts it and won't print it.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I just edited it out but it still don't work. I mean it does not sort the last name. There is no sorted data in output section.